# weblogic cluster between two different server

Tags: linux, centos, java, oracle, weblogic

I have two server (for example 1.1.1.1 , 1.1.1.2).

I want to have one administrator tools and two managed servers (one on 1.1.1.1 and another on 1.1.1.2) and cluster these two nodes.

Is the base of this architecture true and implemented before?

I read oracle documentation but can't find the way to achieve this architecture. 
all the documents are about cluster between two nodes on one server.